# Excel VBA Automated Reconciliation

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel worksheet set up as shown below which lists two types of transactions - Advance Pmt Credit & Refill. The objective is to reconcile this and ensure that each Advance Pmt Credit is offset by a group of Refills.

```
Date    Description  Amount     Grouping    AutoRef Sum Check   Ref Chk
12/7/2012   Refill   (20,000.00)    advpmtcrdt1     0   Ok
12/7/2012   Advance Pmt Credit   20,000.00  advpmtcrdt1 advpmtcrdt1 0   Ok
12/9/2012   Refill   (20,000.00)    advpmtcrdt2     0   Ok
12/9/2012   Refill   (40,000.00)    advpmtcrdt2     0   Ok
12/10/2012  Refill   (20,000.00)    advpmtcrdt2     0   Ok
12/10/2012  Advance Pmt Credit   80,000.00  advpmtcrdt2 advpmtcrdt2 0   Ok
12/11/2012  Refill   (40,000.00)    advpmtcrdt4     -100000 Ok
12/11/2012  Refill   (40,000.00)    advpmtcrdt4     -100000 Ok
12/11/2012  Refill   (20,000.00)    advpmtcrdt3     0   Ok
12/11/2012  Advance Pmt Credit   20,000.00  advpmtcrdt3 advpmtcrdt3 0   Ok
12/12/2012  Refill   (20,000.00)    advpmtcrdt4     -100000 Ok
```

The actual data runs from column 1 to column 3; i use column 4 to assign each record to a group; column 5 has formula to assign each Advance Pmt Credit a numbered ref; column 6 & 7 has some checks to ensure that each group adds to 0 and only 1 Advance Pmt Credit exists in a group.

I need to group the rows by adding a reference in column 4 (Grouping) such that

1. the total of each group should be 0
2. Each group can contain only one 'Advance Pmt Credit'
3. Rule 2 implies that value in col 4 should be same as the reference in col 5, if it is an Advance Pmt Credit.

I tried to write a macro to add the references in col 4 automatically:

```
Sub AutoFill()

Dim Ref As String
Dim rng As Range


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Application.WorksheetFunction

On Error Resume Next
Ref = .VLookup("Unresolved", Range("FullList"), 3, 0)
If Err.Number = "1004" Then Ref = .VLookup("Free", Range("List"), 2, 0)

While .Index(Range("AB:AC"), .Match(Ref, Range("AB:AB"), 0), 1) <> Ok

    On Error Resume Next
    Ref = .VLookup("Unresolved", Range("FullList"), 3, 0)
    If Err.Number = "1004" Then Ref = .VLookup("Free", Range("List"), 2, 0)

    .Index(Range("N:O"), .Match(Ref, Range("O:O"), 0), 1) = Ref

    Set rng = Range("N1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

        While .SumIf(Range("N:N"), Ref, Range("L:L")) <> 0
        If .CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        rng.Value = Ref
        If .Sum(Range("P:P")) < 0 Then rng.Clear
        End If
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
        Wend
Wend

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is what the macro does: check the next unused ref, assign it in col 4 according to rule 3 given above, then start assigning the same ref to the first available blank cells in col 4 utill the sum of the group is 0; if the sum of Refills goes more than the Advance Pmt credit amount, then delete the last updated ref; then find the next available empty cell in col 3 and add the ref; then check the sum again...repeat these steps until all items are balanced.

**Problem:** The macro ran smooth till it made some 15 groups but eneterd an infinite loop in the 16th iteration. This logic fails if the sum of refills exceeds the Advance Pmt credit total after we add a refill to the group. I have uploaded the workbook [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-wCR0PXhVQSLUJzbWplZ2hRZms/edit?usp=sharing).

Can you suggest a better algorithm to achieve this - with or without VBA.

Appreciate your help & suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with your explanation of the rules, I have found it difficult to decipher what your code does.  However, I can match your allocation of rows to groups down to group 15 which is the last your code processes.  My code is successful down to group 35 but fails gracefully with group 36.  I will explain why later.

I have used VBA to place formulae within worksheets but only when those worksheets are dynamic and the formula values will change. That does not seem to be the case here so I have dropped your use of formulae.

I use columns N and O as you do.  I also use column P but only to help you determine how to handle the group 36 failure.  I do not use any of your other working columns.

Like you, I allocate reference numbers to the "Advance Pmt Credit" rows on a first pass and them allocate the other rows to groups on a second pass.  This is not necessary but I believe keeping the two passes separate makes them clearer.

I use column P to record a running total as I allocate rows to a group.  Since you have given column P a heading of "Sum Check", perhaps you meant to do the same.  The value in column P against the last row allocated to a group is always zero.

I fail with group 36 because I run out of rows to allocate to the group before achieving a running total of zero.  Looking at the updated worksheet, it is not obvious to me what rows should be allocated to group 36.

I believe the easiest approach for you would be to create a copy of "Report.xlsb".  Delete columns U to X from the copy and replace your macro AutoFill with mine.

Try my macro.  I have provided little help with the code since I did not want to spent time explaining a solution that might not be appropriate.  I am happy to explain it if you think it could meet your requirements.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AutoFill()

  Const ColDesc As Long = 5
  Const ColAmount As Long = 12
  Const ColRefAll As Long = 14
  Const ColRefAPC As Long = 15
  Const ColTotal As Long = 16
  Const RefPrefix As String = "advpmtcrdt"

  Dim NumRefNext As Long
  Dim RefCrnt As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowPrev As Long
  Dim TotalCrnt As Double

  With Worksheets("AS-Track")

    ' Allocate reference to each "Advance Pmt Credit" row
    ' ===================================================
    RowPrev = 1
    NumRefNext = 1
    ' Find first "Advance Pmt Credit" if any
    Set Rng = .Columns(ColDesc).Find(What:="Advance Pmt Credit", _
                                     After:=Cells(RowPrev, ColDesc), _
                                     SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      ' No "Advance Pmt Credit" in worksheet
      Call MsgBox("""Advance Pmt Credit"" not found", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If

    ' At least one "Advance Pmt Credit" row found.  On entry to this loop
    ' Rng addresses the first "Advance Pmt Credit" row.  For each subsequent
    ' loop, Rng addresses the followint "Advance Pmt Credit" row.
    Do While True
      If Rng.Row <= RowPrev Then
        ' Have looped so all "Advance Pmt Credit" rows have reference
        Exit Do
      End If
      RowCrnt = Rng.Row
      ' Allocate next reference to this "Advance Pmt Credit" row.
      .Cells(RowCrnt, ColRefAPC) = RefPrefix & NumRefNext
      NumRefNext = NumRefNext + 1
      RowPrev = RowCrnt
      Set Rng = .Columns(ColDesc).FindNext(Rng)
    Loop

    ' Allocate other rows to "Advance Pmt Credit" groups
    ' ==================================================

    ' This loop could have been merged with previous loop but I
    ' believe code is more easily understood if they are separate.

    ' Have exited above loop with Rng addressing first
    ' "Advance Pmt Credit" row.

    RowPrev = 1
    Do While True
      If Rng.Row <= RowPrev Then
        ' Have looped so "Advance Pmt Credit" rows have been grouped
        ' with other rows.
        Exit Do
      End If
      RowCrnt = Rng.Row

      ' This is a "Advance Pmt Credit" row.  Group it with previous
      ' non-"Advance Pmt Credit" rows that are not part of another
      ' group until the group total is zero.

      RefCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColRefAPC).Value
      .Cells(RowCrnt, ColRefAll).Value = RefCrnt
      TotalCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColAmount).Value
      With .Cells(RowCrnt, ColTotal)
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00-"
        .Value = TotalCrnt
      End With

      Do While True
        RowCrnt = RowCrnt - 1
        If RowCrnt = 1 Then
          Call MsgBox("I am trying to create the group " & RefCrnt & _
                      " but I reached row 1 with a running total of " & _
                      Format(TotalCrnt, "#,##0.00-"), vbOKOnly)
          Exit Sub
        End If
        If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColRefAll).Value = "" Then
          ' This row has not been allocated
          .Cells(RowCrnt, ColRefAll).Value = RefCrnt
          TotalCrnt = TotalCrnt + .Cells(RowCrnt, ColAmount).Value
          With .Cells(RowCrnt, ColTotal)
            .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00-"
            .Value = TotalCrnt
          End With

          If Abs(TotalCrnt) < 0.009 Then
            ' The total of this group is zero (within the error associated
            ' with holding decimal values as binary).
            Exit Do
          End If
        End If
      Loop

      RowPrev = Rng.Row
      Set Rng = .Columns(ColDesc).FindNext(Rng)
    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Tony, Thanks for your detailed explanation. I will take a look at this and let you know.

Comment: i accept your answer as the data had some extra lines near group 36. Sorry i did not get a chance to do this earlier. Thank you!